# Multithreading win32com: CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream Hangs

Tags: python, multithreading, com, win32com, historian

I am trying to get threading working with a program to query a Historian server, so that concurrent queries can be performed. I want to have a single instance of the server that I can pass around the program, rather than instantiating a server object in every worker thread.

The problem I have is the call to CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream causes the program to hang when using "iHistorian_SDK.Server", but works fine when using something else, for example, "Excel.Application". Is this a limitation with the Historian SDK? is there a way to make it work?

```
import threading
import time

import pythoncom
import win32com.client

def run_in_thread(hist_id):
    # Initialize
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    # Get instance from the id
    hist = win32com.client.Dispatch(
        pythoncom.CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(hist_id, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch))
    time.sleep(5)
    pythoncom.CoUninitialize ()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pythoncom.CoInitialize () # Is this needed in the main thread?
    hist = win32com.client.Dispatch("iHistorian_SDK.Server") #"Excel.Application"
    hist_id = pythoncom.CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(pythoncom.IID_IDispatch, hist)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_in_thread, kwargs={'hist_id': hist_id})
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

Comment: Educated guess: `iHistorian_SDK.Server` is an in-process STA server (a DLL), and as such relies on the host to run a message pump on its behalf, which you don't. `Excel.Application` is an out-of-process server (an EXE), and so it runs its own message pump and doesn't depend on the host's good behavior.

Comment: By calling `CoInitialize()`, your thread has joined a single-threaded apartment (STA). Such a thread is required to retrieve and dispatch window messages in a timely manner; under no circumstances should it block for any significant length of time. Yous doesn't and does, correspondingly. Before you ask, I have no idea how to run a message pump in Python.

Comment: Yes, the Historian SDK Server is a DLL